# CPU upgrade - HP Probook 4540s and Mobile Intel HM76 Express

Tags: cpu, upgrade

I have bought used HP Probook 4540s with Mobile Intel HM76 Express motherboard, with Intel Core i7 3610qm which needs 45W. My motherboard is providing 35W. On the HP Probook 4540s site this processor isn't listed as compatible, but on the motherboard it is. What do you think about that, should I keep it or not?

Answer (score 0):

These are the processors sold with that model and are guaranteed to work, everything else is an experiment.

[image]

[Source](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/manualsResults/?sp4ts.oid=5229455&spf_p.tpst=psiContentResults&spf_p.prp_psiContentResults=wsrp-navigationalState%3Daction%253Dmanualslist%257Ccontentid%253DService-and-maintenance%257Clang%253Den&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)

Comment: Ok, I understand that but I like to hear some thoughts on this topic. Everything is compatible except that tdp of my processor is greater than recommended by 10W. Except maybe some heating problems can it make some damage? Does anyone have similar experience?